# This program word wraps file, want to add a feature where if i supply a file directory and it has another file directory in it to also wrap those file

Tags: c, recursion, directory

so basically when the user enters in the command line ./ww -r 10 (name of directory)
i want it to word wrap whatever is in the specified directory and check if it has a sub directory within that directory and wrap that as well.... im stuck...  i know that de-type==8 gives me a file type but im not sure what to do after this,.... im trying to make this recursive, right now it works perfectly with the first part if i supply a directory or file it will word wrap all those files in there, however i cant seem to figuire out how to check if the folder has subdirectories and i  think the way im coding it would only really work once to check if its a subdirectory, because what if that subdirectory has a subdirectory that contains more files etc etc, do i make a  function? do i start a pthread? is it possible to create a pthread in a if statement? C programming

```
if(argc  == 3 || argc==4) {
    if(argv[1][0]=='-'&& argv[1][1]=='r'){
        file_width=atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("Entered file with with the speical 'R' command is: %d\n",file_width);
        dir = opendir(argv[3]);
        while ((de = readdir(dir))) {
            if(de->d_name[0] == '.' || (strncmp(de->d_name,"wrap",4) == 0)) {
                if (DEBUG) printf("File ignored.\n");
                continue;                                                                   // ignore (.) and already wrapped files
            }
            if(de->d_type==8){
              
            }
            char s[270] = "wrap.";                                                          // temporary string for output file
            chdir(argv[3]);
            fd_in = open(de->d_name, O_RDONLY);                                             // read current file in the directory
            fd_out = open(strcat(s,de->d_name),O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND | O_TRUNC, 0600);    // create output file
            
            if (DEBUG) printf("Current file name is: %s\n", de->d_name);
          
            
            word_wrap(fd_in,fd_out);
            close(fd_in);
            close(fd_out);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently Traverse Directory Tree with opendir(), readdir() and closedir()](//stackoverflow.com/q/2312110/90527)

Answer (score 0):

You already say you're *trying to make this recursive*, so the simple answer to "*do i make a function?*" is "yes". This function essentially contains your code from the `opendir` line to the end of the block, with some adjustments, especially the changes of the current working directory and the recursive function call, e. g.:

```
void wrapdir(const char *dirname)
{
    if (chdir(dirname) != 0) { perror(dirname); return; }   // minimal error check
    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *de;
    int fd_in, fd_out;
    while (de = readdir(dir))
    {
        if (de->d_name[0] == '.' || strncmp(de->d_name, "wrap", 4) == 0)
        {
            if (DEBUG) printf("File ignored.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (de->d_type == DT_DIR) { wrapdir(de->d_name); continue; }
        char s[270] = "wrap.";
        fd_in = open(de->d_name, O_RDONLY);
        fd_out = open(strcat(s, de->d_name), O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_TRUNC, 0600);
        if (DEBUG) printf("Current file name is: %s\n", de->d_name);
        word_wrap(fd_in, fd_out);
        close(fd_in);
        close(fd_out);
    }
    closedir(dir);
    chdir("..");
}
```

(Since you already used the `d_type` member with a known value, you're obviously satisfied with the code working on systems such as GNU/Linux where this extension is available, but note that only some filesystems have full support for it.)

The above function can be initially called by replacing the moved code in `main` with

```
            wrapdir(argv[3]);
```